# How to upload files outside root folder in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have my project folder on Ubuntu instance at:  **/workspace/myproject**

Till now, I used to store uploaded files at location:  **/myproject/public/uploads**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var savePath = 'public/uploads/';
var filename = uuid.v4() + '.jpg';
var base64 = new Buffer(requestParams[constant.DATA], 'base64');
fs.writeFile(savePath + filename, base64, function(error) {
});
```

I want to save my uploaded files at: **/workspace/uploads**

instead of inside the public folder. Also, I don't want to write absolute path in my code.

Any other idea?

Comment: You ^should* use a configurable absolute path, or at least a root. Why don't you want to? You want to write to an absolute path-so use one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save a file in a folder within the parent directly, then you could use `../` to go back a level. Like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var savePath = __dirname + '/../uploads/';
var filename = uuid.v4() + '.jpg';
var base64 = new Buffer(requestParams[constant.DATA], 'base64');
fs.writeFile(savePath + filename, base64, function(error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use __dirname to get the current directory or ./relative path